# Access SqlCeDB with relative path to sdf on VS2010

Tags: .net, sql, publish

I have a SqlCeDB as part of my project, right now the connection string is the following:

public String localDBConnectionString = @"C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MapProjectDB.sdf";

Obviously this is going to fail when I publish it and put it on another machine.  How can I make the connection string work if its both in Debug mode and also if it has been Published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have faced the same problem , was able to rectify by putting it in the following form

SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database1.sdf");